# SQL Server 2000 Trigger validation

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2000

I have inherited an older system that has multiple programs using one SQL Server 2000 database. I can't change the software and one of the programs is randomly performing a destructive update that sets some columns to null.

The best solution I can come up with is to create an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger to validate the update and only allow it if does not contain a null value. I can't count on the SQL command being done in a transaction that I can roll back using an `AFTER` trigger. Proper parameterized SQL is being used.

What we can't figure out is:

1. How to check the value of a `@parameter` here, and
2. If it's ok, allow the original SQL command to execute.

Appreciate any ideas!

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trd_tablename] 
ON [dbo].[tablename]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF @parameter IS NOT NULL
        --run the original statement
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent updates to a table, with an exception for one situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507012/how-to-prevent-updates-to-a-table-with-an-exception-for-one-situation)

Comment: All the moving parts are in the duplicate question, you just have to re-arrange them slightly. Two key points: **#1** There is no `@parameter` in DML triggers. There are `deleted` and `inserted` tables which contain all affected rows as they were and as they will be (in the case of `INSTEAD OF` triggers - as they *would* be). **#2** Triggers do not run once per row. They run once *per transaction*. Always write them in a way that correctly handles one to N affected rows.