# How to prevent tree having circular references

Tags: sql-server, tree, constraints

original table is more complicated but..
i got a table which stores great many trees inside like;
what im looking is a nontrigger mothod like constraint or a trigger which decides to rollback very fast..

```
create table myTreeTable ( 
    id int not null identity(1,1),
    node varchar(80),
    parent varchar(80),
    constraint PK_mytable primary key nonclustered (node)
)

insert into myTreeTable values ('a', null)
insert into myTreeTable values ('b', 'a')
insert into myTreeTable values ('c', 'a')
insert into myTreeTable values ('d', 'a')
insert into myTreeTable values ('e', 'b')
insert into myTreeTable values ('f', 'b')
insert into myTreeTable values ('g', 'd')
insert into myTreeTable values ('h', 'f')
insert into myTreeTable values ('i', 'g')
insert into myTreeTable values ('j', 'g')

insert into myTreeTable values ('aa', null)
insert into myTreeTable values ('bb', 'aa')
insert into myTreeTable values ('cc', 'aa')
insert into myTreeTable values ('dd', 'aa')
insert into myTreeTable values ('ee', 'bb')
insert into myTreeTable values ('ff', 'bb')
insert into myTreeTable values ('gg', 'dd')
insert into myTreeTable values ('hh', 'ff')
insert into myTreeTable values ('ii', 'gg')
insert into myTreeTable values ('jj', 'gg')
```

what i need to prevent is 
an update like

```
update myTreeTable set parent='j' where ID=1
```

or an insert like

```
insert into myTreeTable values ('aaa', 'bbb'),('bbb', 'ccc'),('ccc','aaa')
```

Comment: "what im looking is a nontrigger mothod like constraint or a trigger"...how is a trigger a non-trigger method? Using a constraint for this would be pretty much the same thing as a trigger. You are going to have to use a recursive cte, possibly even two of them because you will have to traverse the tree both directions from the row being updated.

Comment: (what im looking is a nontrigger mothod like constraint) or (a trigger  which decides to rollback very fast)

Comment: Ahh wasn't getting that before. At any rate, you will need a recursive cte or two here.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if circular references or not by bellow query:

```sql
create trigger check_circular_ref_tgr on myTreeTable for insert, update as
begin

declare @new_node varchar(80), @new_parent varchar(80)

select @new_node=node, @new_parent=parent from inserted

with p(id) as (
select parent from myTreeTable where node = @new_parent
union all 
select parent from myTreeTable inner join p on myTreeTable.node=p.id where parent is not null)

if exists(select id from p where id=@new_node)
  raiseerror(N'circular reference error', 10, 1)

end
```

Comment: could solve the problem but table got to many records.. so selecting few times from them can be a problem.. especially in every update..

Comment: i ve used a function very similar to yours.
which decides if a node has itself as its ancestor. and every node checks themselfs on changes.. which worked very well.. at the end its a circle.. if a node makes a circle, every node gets in that circle.. checking 1 node was enough..

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `Instead of` Trigger to override Updates and Inserts. See this SO post: [How to prevent updates to a table, with an exception for one situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507012/how-to-prevent-updates-to-a-table-with-an-exception-for-one-situation)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "Descendants" table where for each pair of nodes you record whether one node is a descendant of another.  It is going to have way fewer than N*N rows, because you do not need entries for nodes that are completely unrelated.  (Absence of an entry means "not a descendant".)

This will give the fastest performance when searching, but it will incur a performance penalty when inserting/deleting, because you will have to update the "Descendants" table.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that checks to see if a insert/change will create a circular reference and call it from a CHECK CONSTRAINT.